# passing dropdownlist selected value to controller through html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to pass some values from model and dropdownlist selected value/item into controller through Html.ActionLink method, but can't find any suitable way. I am giving my code below -

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryId)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EntryId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EntryId)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryDate)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EntryDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Check Information</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Check.CheckId)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Check.CheckId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Check.CheckId)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Check.CheckTitle)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Check.CheckTitle)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comments</legend>
        <div class="span4">
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Comment", "AddComment", new { Model.EntryId }) &nbsp;
            @Html.ActionLink("View All Comments", "ViewAllComments", new { Model.Check.CheckId })
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Serial
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Comment
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckCommentsList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Comment)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Comment)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus, new SelectList(Model.CommentStatusList, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus.ToString()), new {@id="ddlCommentStatus"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus)
                            @*@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus)*@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Update Status", "UpdateCommentStatus", new { Model.EntryId, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial, Model.CheckCommentsList[i].CommentStatus, Model.Check.CheckId })|
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteComment", new { Model.CheckCommentsList[i].Serial, Model.EntryId })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCommentStatus(string entryId, int serial, string status, string checkId)
{
    var securityInformation = new SecurityInformation();
    securityInformation.MemberId = (string)Session["MemberId"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityInformation.MemberId))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "MemberLogIn");
    }

    var commentStatus = (CommentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof (CommentStatus), status);
    new CheckDataManager().UpdateCheckDataCommentStatus(entryId, serial, commentStatus);

    return RedirectToAction("ViewAllComments", new { checkId });
}
```

Please note that, CommentStatus is an Enum. I am always getting null for status variable in controller. Can anyone show me the way to do it. If JQuery is the solution, then please give an example as I am new at JQuery.

Comment: yes, jquery should be a better way. The components you want would be 1) an anchor tag 2) an event handler 3) a jquery selector 4) `.Ajax` or .`Post` to your controller

Comment: @DaveA, can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Take your best shot at implementing each piece (post an answer) and I will help as you run into obstacles. Start with anchor and event handler. Google JQuery event handlers. Then move onto the selector.

Comment: I have done this thing differently to meet the deadline. But I will go with you tomorrow to learn the thing. Thanks.